# Role of return in C functions, does it return the value of the variable called?

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

after some research, due to not really clear example in chapter 1.7 in "the C Programming language" by K & R, I understood that `return` is conventionally present at the end of each function, marking its end;
it seems that by default, the value of return is `0`, which means that the function was performed successfully (which exactly means what?).
what happens if we set the value of return to the variable we call?
for example, if I will write:

```
return p;
```

does it mean that the final value of the funcion will be `p`?
So for example, if I call this funcion from `main()`, or another function, will the value of this function, inside `main()` be `p`?

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int power(int m, int n);
/* test power function */
int main(){
    
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        printf("%d %2d %3d", i, power(2,i), power(-3,i));
    return 0;
    }


int power(int base, int n)
{
    int i, p;
    p=1;

    for(i=1;i<=n;++i)
        p=p*base;

    return p;
}
```

does it mean that when i call `power()` in main its value is `p`?

Comment: Did you try to compile the code to see what happens?

Comment: I think you're confused because the `main` function has different rules than every other function. So when you read that section, you need to be careful to separate the paragraphs that talk about `main` from the paragraphs that talk about other functions. For example, the statement *"it seems that by default, the value of return is 0"* **only applies to `main`**. That's not true for any other function.

Comment: The return is not the variable p.  It is a copy of the value which p held.  p is a local variable, so it is gone after power returns.

Comment: Yeah this is the thing, that there are few elements which I don't get clearly, so yes @klutt, I tried the code, but I don't get how it does, I made some try to simulate it with simpler approach but I failed, so i didn't understand how it works. I also thought parameters were local and the name of them was purely formal, so I cannot translate in a kind of human language let's say the `p = p * base`, I mean, what is the value of base supposed to be in there? the book is not saying it explicitly, and I cannot assume with certanty as it's clear

Comment: the same goes for parameter `n`, I would say it is indefinite so it is huge number, but I don't feel sure enough as to assume it, after all, I am just beginner, so I think, it should be stated clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value returned by `power` is the value of `p`.

We might say "`power` returned `p`" for short, but it's the value of `p` that's returned.

---

Functions don't have a value; functions return a value.

`p` is not a value; `p` is a variable.

The value returned by `power` is the value of `p` when `return p` is evaluated. So if the value of `p` is `8`, the value returned is `8`.

The above program passes the returned value to `printf` to print.

---

> it seems that by default, the value of return is `0`

Functions don't have a default return value. If the function has a return type other than `void`, `return` must be used.

`main` is the sole exception. `return 0` is the default for `main`.

Comment: Thanks, this was the answer fot the specific question,  but could I also ask you, what are the values of `base` and `n`? I got this is local to the function, but I would say they have no specific value, does this mean they are kind of infinite (in a mathematical limit kind of point of view)?

Comment: It depends on the arguments provided. If the call was `power(2, 4)`, then `base`'s value would be `2`, and `n`'s would be `4`.

Comment: It is a possible for variable to have "no specific value". It's called uninitialized. And you're not allowed to read the values of such variables. Example of bad code: `int x; printf("%d\n", x);` Fixed: `int x; x=3; printf("%d\n", x);`

Comment: oh, wow, yeah now it makes sense, finally, thanks! @ikegami